# Discord.js - Music Bot . It plays any video, but not Copyrighted Music

Tags: youtube, discord, discord.js, audio-player

This Command plays any video just fine, but if it's a video music or something with music, it doesn't play anything
What should I do?

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

   if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('Please connect to a voice channel to play music.')
   if (message.guild.me.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('Bot is already connected.')
   if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please put a working Youtube Link.')

   let validate = await ytdl.validateURL(args[0])

   if (!validate) return message.channel.send('The link is not working.')


   let connection =  await message.member.voiceChannel.join()
   let stream = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'})
   let dispatcher = await connection.playStream(stream)
   dispatcher.on('end', _end => {message.member.voiceChannel.leave()})
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: 'music',
    aliases: []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your filter:

```js
let stream = ytdl(args[0])
```

That looks like to could be filtering the wrong things.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core < npm readme

> filter - Used to decide what format to download. Can be audioandvideo to filter formats
>   that contain both video and audio, video to filter for formats that contain video, or
>   videoonly for formats that contain video and no additional audio track. Can also be
>   audio or audioonly. You can give a filtering function that gets called with each format
>   available. This function is given the format object as its first argument, and should
>   return true if the format is preferable.

If it is not that, YouTube its self could be doing something on its end.